# jQuery CSS - Write into the <style>-tag

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

I want to change the `background-color` of the `body` of my HTML document. My problem is that jQuery adds the style to the `body` tag, but I want to change the value in the `style` tag. Is this possible using jQuery?

**Example-Code**

```
    <style title="css_style" type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color:#dc2e2e;     /* <- CHANGE THIS */
      color:#000000;
      font-family:Tahoma, Verdana;
      font-size:11px;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      background-image: url(http://abc.de/image.jpg);
    }
    </style>

    ...

    <body>
       // ....
    </body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('body').css('background-color','#ff0000');
```

**Result**

```
<body style="background-color:#ff0000;">
   // ....
</body>
```

Comment: try `$('style').text(...new definition...)` -- haven't tested though; I don't know any jQuery automation for this.

Comment: Give the style tag an id and call using its id. Something like: $('#{id}').attr('style', 'background-color:#ff0000;');

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The are specific methods for manipulating stylesheets,

DOM: [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)
Microsoft: [addRule()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358796%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I just made a method for jQuery(maybe somebody else already did, I don't know)

```
(
function( $ )
{
  $.style={
          insertRule:function(selector,rules,contxt)
          {
            var context=contxt||document,stylesheet;

            if(typeof context.styleSheets=='object')
            {
              if(context.styleSheets.length)
              {
                stylesheet=context.styleSheets[context.styleSheets.length-1];
              }
              if(context.styleSheets.length)
              {
                if(context.createStyleSheet)
                {
                  stylesheet=context.createStyleSheet();
                }
                else
                {
                  context.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(context.createElement('style'));
                  stylesheet=context.styleSheets[context.styleSheets.length-1];
                }
              }
              if(stylesheet.addRule)
              {
                for(var i=0;i<selector.length;++i)
                {
                  stylesheet.addRule(selector[i],rules);
                }
              }
              else
              {
                stylesheet.insertRule(selector.join(',') + '{' + rules + '}', stylesheet.cssRules.length);  
              }
            }
          }
        };
  }
)( jQuery );
```

Example usage:

```
$.style.insertRule(['p','h1'], 'color:red;')
$.style.insertRule(['p'],      'text-decoration:line-through;')
$.style.insertRule(['div p'],  'text-decoration:none;color:blue')
```

the second argument should be clear, the rules. As optional 3rd argument the context-document can be supplied.
The first argument are the selectors as array-elements.
Note that you dont have to use there different selector separated by comma, as MSIE only accepts  "Single contextual selectors" as argument for addRule()

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ubDDd/

Comment: Is there any way to manipulate existing rules in a style tag?

Comment: @Jakobud: yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information

Comment: Interesting. How come libraries like jQuery choose to add inline styles to every selected element instead of manipulating stylesheets like this? Seems magnitudes more efficient.

Comment: Interesting question, I've never thought about it. The primary reason may be that selecting elements in jQuery is more complex, in many cases the selection couldn't be translated into a CSS-selector.

Comment: There is indeed a jQuery plugin to manipulate stylesheets https://github.com/f0r4y312/jquery-stylesheet, you might want to check that @Jakobud

Answer (score 132):

While not changing an existing style element, this works as a cross-browser way to create a new one:

```
$( "<style>body { background: black; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )
```

By cascading, it'll override existing styles, which should do the trick.

Comment: Best, cleanest answer. Tested it in Chrome and IE8 (in IE7 mode).

My only change is appendTo("head"), instead of "body", since style tags should only be included in the head (unless, of course, the HTML5 "scoped" attribute is included on the style tag, but since this is not supported by any browsers at the moment, we can ignore this option).

Comment: @EarlJenkins I've updated it to say appendTo("head"), thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For some reason, I wasn't sure if this would work consistently in all browsers. Good to know it works.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery always adds its CSS in the tag itself.

I think you should use the `append()` function with a new body style rule.

Like this:

```
var newRule = "body{ /*your CSS rule here...*/ }";
$("style").append(newRule);
```

or

```
$("body").css({ /*CSS rule...*/ });
```

I hope this is what you meant...

Comment: for some reason this fails in IE7.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it's easier to copy all the existing rules to a string, add your stuff or modify what's in there, delete the existing tag and replacing it modified, like so:

```
//Initialize variable
var cssRules = '';
//Copy existing rules
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length; i++) {
    cssRules += document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].cssText;
}
//Delete existing node
$('style').remove();

// .... Add stuff to cssRules

//Append new nodes
$('<style>' + cssRules + '</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer that I used in my own project to create a list of separate CSS rules that were inlined in the head.

Comment: Upvoted this not because it's the best way to answer the question, but because it opens up a whole new way of thinking about the problem that could be useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to modify the  section by adding to it's html.

```
var styleText = $('style').html();
styleText += '\n' + '#TabName div ul li a {border-top-left-radius:5px;}';
$('style').html(styleText);
```

Answer (score 3):

As commented above, `jqueryEl.text` should also work:

```
$("<style/>").text(css).appendTo(document.head);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your body class but you cannot change your style tag:

#### HTML:

```
<style title="css_style" type="text/css">
.highlight
{
    background-color:#ff0000;   
}
</style>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('body').toggleClass(".highlight");
```

Comment: In CSS `highlight` has to have the class-selector `.`: `.highlight { .. }`

Answer (score 1):

My page had multiple style tags, so needed a slightly more surgical approach.

I riffed on Asinus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117000/399007), and expanded it to grab the rules from ALL stylesheets, but only where the stylesheet came from a `<style>` tag.

```
var cssRules = '';
//Copy existing rules for <style> tags
for (var i=0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){
    var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    if (stylesheet.ownerNode.tagName !== 'STYLE'){ 
        continue
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < stylesheet.cssRules.length; j++) {
        cssRules += stylesheet.cssRules[j].cssText;
        cssRules += '\n'
    }
}

jQuery('style').remove(); //Delete existing node
cssRules += '*, :before, :after {animation: none !important;}' //Add new rules
jQuery('<style>' + cssRules + '</style>').appendTo('head'); //Append new nodes
```