# jquery change css property on wildcard

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a wildcard id. I would like to change the display on the wildcard not the actual element.

```
#mywildcard{
display:none;
}
<div id = "mywildcard"></div>
```

When I click a button or something I would like to change the actual property display not add a style to the element.

I want

```
#mywildcard{
display:block;
}
```

What I am getting now is

```
<div id = "mywildcard" style="display:block"></div>
#mywildcard{
display:block;//Firebug show crossed out.
}
```

I tried 
`$('#mywildcard).css('display','block');` and it just added a style to that element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to either use the jquery function [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), depending on the type of effect you are trying to achieve.

Calling `.toggle()` on the element will detect if it is display none, then it will revert back to its default display. If it is currently showing (`display:block`) then calling `.toggle()` again will hide the element.

If instead you want to do a one time change from `display:none` to `display:block`, then you'll want to use the `.show()` function.

To be more specific, let's say you are trying to attach to `.show()` function to form button with an id of `wildcardShowBtn`. To achieve that in jQuery you would do:

```
$("#wildcardShowBtn").click(function () {
   $("#mywildcard").show();
});
```

Comment: That is the opposite of what he asked for. .show will use the style attribute stye="display:block" which he is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

try this (it sounds like this is what you want)

document.getElementById('mywildcard').setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');

Comment: That is the opposite of what he asked for. Using the style attribute stye="display:block" is exactly what he said he doesn't want.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to edit the css rule #wildcard from an external css file, but you can do it if its on the page in a style tag. Or if you are dead set on having it in an external css file, this should still work out.

What you want to do is edit the rule not the element, so target the style tag instead:

```
 $('style[id=mystyle]').html( $('style[id=mystyle]').html().replace('none','block') );`
```

something like this will find the style tag and replace instances of 'none', with 'block'

BUT if your rule is in an external stylesheet you can use js to create a new style tag with the rule inside it.

[jQuery CSS - Write into the <style>-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag) //second answer

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-130717.html //tutorial on dynamically creating styles