# How can I change cssText in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

In the past I've been able to modify the CSS on a page via an inline style tag.
I know this sounds horrible but it's for custom CSS writing while working on a kind of WYSIWYG (not with text though).

I used to do something like:
`tag.styleSheet.cssText = myrules;`

I don't know when exactly, but at some point IE started saying "Invalid Argument" when I try this. The real crux is that doing `tag.innerHTML = 'body {}'` gives `Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined` which doesn't happen in any other browser.

**EDIT**

To be clear I am using an inline style tag. I am not trying to use the inline style attribute.

`<style type="text/css" id="mytag"></style>`

How can I change the inside of that tag?

**EDIT 2**
Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tTr5d/

It appears that my solution of tag.styleSheet.cssText is identical to using styleSheets property. You can comment out the last definition of cssText to see it working as proposed by @Teemu. So now I'm real lost why it's not working in my app. If anyone has ideas what could break that functionality that would be great. In the meantime I'll be tinkering around my app.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag

Comment: @SupremeDud I tried `styleSheet.addRule( 'body', 'background-color:#FF0000' );` in my doc and it just returned a number, one for each rule added, but I didn't see the CSS update visually. Granted I'm going directly to the sheet rather than using styleSheets, I know it's a function there

Comment: @SupremeDud see my answer which is very different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE is limited to 32 stylesheets. I like to forget that fact apparently, which seems to include inline style tags, on top of `<link>`.

I changed my sandbox to turn on minification so it would put the files together.

Then my code worked.

So it appears that when you go over the limit and insert via JS, you don't get a real error until you try what I did.

Comment: +1 - You make my day, mate ;) Thanks, I've spent all morning looking for a solution until found your answer.

Comment: I keep forgetting this, too, and keep coming back to SO to be reminded that it would have been nice if IE (a) didn't impose this restriction like it was 1996 and (b) actually gave an error message that indicated the cause of the actual problem rather than being vague about it, especially when they know the exact cause for the error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to a `styleSheet` object only via `styleSheets` collection (or `imports` collection). If you refer direct to the `style` element, you'll just get a HTML-element. (Check properties in both objects within simple `for..in`-loop, and see the difference)

This works in all IEs, and results are rendered immediately:

```
document.styleSheets['mytag'].addRule('BODY', 'background-color:red');
```

More info in [MSDN: styleSheet object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hmm... It seems that my answer is partly wrong. Your code really works with dynamically created style sheets, but when they are literally written in the `head`, it fails. Why that happens, unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Comment: Oh man that's an excellent point of difference. I thought that they were always dynamically created. Now I'm gonna check to see if the tag was put into the HTML without me knowing by another dev ( or I forgot about it since it's from so long ago )

Comment: I got swamped with other tasks and finally had a chance to look. These tags are always dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. If it's the inline style, you can use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

```
$("#myElement").attr('style')
```

otherwise, you can see what [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) has to offer. You can use that to get and set various CSS styles.

[Other CSS related jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/)

Comment: I'm using an inline style tag like `<style type="text/css">.myelements { ... }</style>` I build up a stylesheet that is then saved off and used later when the user isn't editing

Answer (score 0):

I never had much luck with style elements  and IE's innerHTML.
The dom methods are surer, even if you need to branch for IE;

without jquery-

```
function addNewStyle(str, title){
    var el= document.createElement('style');
    if(title) el.title= title;
    if(el.styleSheet) el.styleSheet.cssText= str;
    else el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
    return el;
}
```

Comment: I still get the error with cssText, even if I use it before appending