# Append css code to <style>

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append css code to a `<style>`.

I have already `<style>` which  have `id` like `<style id="custom-css">` and I want to append more styles when I click a button.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.class{background:#aaa;}').appendTo('custom-css');
});
```

Comment: That won't work, you're adding text and treating it as an element ?

Comment: Yes I know it wont work, I just giving an example.

Comment: Whatever you think you need this for, don't. If you need to edit the <style> tag, you are doing things wrong.

Comment: Are you searching for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag

Comment: It's possible: http://jsfiddle.net/grr7j/ - but, as others have said, it's best not to go down this route. Try applying the style directly with `.css()`.

Comment: I am adding live css code for styling my body, So I am trying to do this. If there is any better solution then suggest me. I dont want to use `css()` cuz I am adding CSS code

Comment: You don't want to use `css()` because you are adding CSS code? That is what `css()` (also) does.

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you would need to ever do this since it seems you could achieve the same result by just setting your rule in advance and the adding and removing another class to turn it on and off but:

```
$('#custom-css').append('.class{background:#aaa;}');
```

a better approach would be to set the rule in advance:

```
<style>
.class {background:none;}
.class.toggleOn {background:#aaa;}


</style>
```

and then some script like

```
$('.class').someEvent(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('toggleOn');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this:

```
$('#custom-css').html(function (i, m) {
    return m+'.class{background:#aaa;}';
});
```

HTML:

```
<style id="custom-css">
    .class-1{background:#aaa;}
</style>
<div class="class-1">HDUYD7DY</div>
<div class="class">F8HR</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grr7j/

However, I'd advise against this method and instead use:

```
$('.class').css('background', '#aaa');
```

Without knowing what the style is for it's a little difficult to recommend a real alternative.