# Is it possible to select a style element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know that I can select all elements with a specified class and modify their properties using css(). But how do I modify the style sheet directly? I want to do this so that any new HTML elements I create will be created with the correct computed width and height.

```
$('.box').css('width', widthValue + 'px');
```

This will work but when I create a new element such as.....

```
let newBox = $('<div class="box"></div>');
```

This will not, of course, inherit the width I set previously. So I was wondering, how do I modify the box class style herself?

Answer (score 1):

Write an style for your `.box` class, and when you will create an element with class `.box` it will get the style

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  var element = $('<div class="box">Second</div>');
  $('body').append(element);
})
```

```css
.box{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class='box'>First Div</div>
 <button id='btn'>Create Second Div</button>
</body>
```

Comment: But the width is computed.

Comment: @tomwrong if it is computed, then compute and add as css

Comment: Thanks Suren, but I'm not sure I have communicated this very maybe. I want to change modify the style. I know of many ways to modify it afterwards, but I have a lot of these to do and I'm looking for a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create element with some properties:

```
$('<div>', {"class": 'box', style: "width: "+widthValue+"px"});
```

It will generate new element such as `<div class="box" style="width: 100px"></div>`

Comment: but that would be the same as $('div class="box" style="width:' + widthValue + 'px">'); Thanks but this is not the answer I'm after.

Comment: @tomwrong See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag