# How can i make the jQuery's .css() method generate external styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an app which relies a lot on jQuery's .css() method. But i have a problem, i don't like inline css styles. I prefer to add them on the **style** tag.
So whenever i make a css style using jQuery, i write something like this;

```
$('element').css({background: 'green'});
```

and the result will be 
`<element style='background: green'>`

Is there a way to make the .css() method generate external styles like the below  example.

```
<style> 
element{
background: green;
}
</style>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could always define the styles using a class in CSS like -

```
.element{
    background : green;
}
```

and use jQuery method to add that class along with the element.

```
$('div').addClass('element');
```

Comment: no this is not what i want. I want to use jquery for my app because the 'element' that i have included in the example may change

Comment: So you need to have that style for that element even if it changes?

Comment: this is an example, my code might look like this  var getclass = 'the clciked element's class'; $(getclass).css({background: variablebg});

Comment: Did you look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag at this before?
I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: In that case, define different classes with the different background colors you want and add and remove the classes to your element accordingly.
Add Class - https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
Remove Class - https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/