# Styling the form placeholder using attribute styling or some inline styling hack

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been doing some research on how to put inline styles for form placeholders and I know that pseudo-selectors can't be put into the inline CSS but there were some hacks using attributes for hover like:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.color=red;" onmouseout="this.style.color='blue';">...</a>
```

can I achieve the same for showing, hiding and styling the placeholders in the input fields using some hack?

I can't use internal or external styles for my text field placeholders as this is a custom in house CMS application that uses inline styling and placeholders can have ***any*** color.

Comment: _"his is a CMS based application"_ - You haven't mentioned the CMS though. What CMS is this? There might be a way to change that behavior or how that inline style is generated.

Comment: @Joseph I updated the question, this is a custom CMS that we are developing.

Comment: You should avoid having `onmouseover` or `onmouseout` and the like in your markup.

Comment: @Ihazkode I know but that is the only thing that may work I belive cause I can't see any other way for this

Comment: @Pete I need to add colors to it, a color pallete with any color so I don't know how to put this like I can't create a lot of classes for a lot of colors?

Comment: @Pete this basically is a Drag and Drop type CMS and I know there are some design issues but for this particular case, I may need to re-write a lot of logic and maybe instead of giving full control I should allow them to use some fixed number of colors for placeholders.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag