# How to add media-rules dynamically to a element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I want to add some media-rules flexible to some of the elements in a website. If I click an element a kind of toolbar will be opened to change the CSS-styles for a specific media-rule. So far so good...

My first idea was simple, to do it with inline-style but media rules could not use in inline-style.

So I have to look for another way how I can add dynamically these rules.

Maybe I create a new style-set dynamically.

```
<style>
@media screen and  (min-width:920px) {}
@media screen and  (min-width:720px) {}
@media screen and  (max-width:580px) {}
</style>
```

But, I don't know...

1. How I can add new classes exactly to this new style-set (I have other style-declaration, and all in the style-tag without a id to use as a selector.)
2. If I find a way to select this style-set, how can I put the new classes into the wanted media rule - which kind of selector I have to use?

As an example, I want to add this new class `".newclass{font-size:12px;}"` to the media rules `"min-width:920px`"

```
$("UNKOWN_SELECTOR").html/append/something_else("\
    .newclass {\
        font-size: 12px;\
    }")
    .appendTo("UNKONWN_SECOND_SELECTOR_TO_MEDIARULE");
```

At the end I want to have this result

```
 <style>
    @media screen and  (min-width:920px) { .newclass{font-size:12px;} }
    @media screen and  (min-width:720px) {}
    @media screen and  (max-width:580px) {}
    </style>
```

I hope someone can tell me a easier way, to solve this.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why forcing media rules without changing media? You can toggle class name of element using jquery `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: at the beginning i have no mediarules, i want to add them by need

Comment: @mikeD what is the reason for doing it this way? Its seems to be going about it backwards - media queries let you define the rules so they are automatically applied... You're not just adding extra processing, but you're doing it on the client side which will slow down the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create classes seperately for each media and add that classes to your element with `media-query`.

For example,

```
.desktop {
     /* styles */
}


.mobile {
     /* styles */
}
```

Add one of those classes to the element with `media-query`

```
@media(max-width: 960px){
    /* add desktop class to your specific element */
}

@media(max-width: 480px){
    /* add mobile class to your specific element */
}
```

Of course you can mix it with your event handler such as `onClick()`

Comment: ok, please have a look, i've update my post. How or wich selectors i have to use, to matche the wanted style-set and matched the wanted media-rule?

Answer (score 0):

You should define all mandatory class names in your styles and use `addClass` and `removeClass` to apply new rules to elements.

Please check this snippet and inspect element after click and before click and check its class name:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("defaultClass").addClass("newClass");
    })
})
```

```css
.defaultClass{
    font-size:20px;
}

.newclass{
    font-size:20px;
}

@media screen and  (min-width:920px) { 
    .newclass{font-size:12px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="defaultClass">Change Font size by clicking Here</a>
```

**Edit:** If you dont want to predefine all classes then you can use `insertRule` to create new css rules on the fly and then use the method I described. Please check [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag) for more details.

Comment: good idear, but it's not possible to add hundreds possible classes for a website, if at the end only some of then really in use

Comment: Please check the edit I have added at the end of answer. @mikeD

Comment: yes, that is what i need (but only if i can insert a new class, not only rule), but my question is wich selector i have to use to insert a new rule in the wanted style-set and in the wanted-media-rule

Comment: Please refere to this tutorial about modifying css rules https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets @mikeD