# Problem stylizing ":after" selector with jQuery's .append() method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, selector

I've been struggling to stylize a div by accessing the ":after" selector with jQuery.

I appended a card looking like this before a certain div:

```
let tempHtml = `
  <div class="card" id="${objectId}">
    <div>
      <a href="#register-popup" onclick="openEditPopup()">
        <img src="${image}">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#register-popup" onclick="openEditPopup()" class="menu-name"><br>${nameKr}</a>
      <div class="price">￦ ${numberWithCommas(price)}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

let category = categories[menuType];
$(`.${category} > div > div.last-card`).before(tempHtml);
```

And then below the card, I tried to add a label that says either "SALE" or "SOLD," depending on the status of the item I'm selling. What I tried is this:

```
if (isDiscounted > 0) {
  $(`#${objectId} > div > div.price`).html(`<del>￦ ${numberWithCommas(price)}</del><br> → ￦ ${numberWithCommas(price - isDiscounted)}`);
  $(`#${objectId}`).append(`<style type="text/css">div#${objectId}:after {display: block; position:fixed; height: 1rem; width: 35px; padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; margin: 10px 0 0 40px; background-color: #f07303; color: #ffffff; font-size: 0.8rem; content: "SALE"}</style>`);
}

if (isSoldOut === true) {
  $(`#${objectId}  > div > a`).append(`<style type="text/css">#${objectId} > div > a > img {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: gray;}</style>`);
  $(`#${objectId} > div > div.price`).append(`<style type="text/css">#${objectId} > div > div.price:after {display: block; height: 1rem; width: 35px; padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; margin: 10px 0 0 40px; background-color: #818181; color: #ffffff; font-size: 0.8rem; content: "SOLD";}</style>`);
}
```

The first ".html()" method works just fine, but all the rest .append() lines won't do their work to add the label to the card. When I first tested this locally on PyCharm, they worked beautifully. The only difference is that my HTML document is now interacting with the server. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: you should be using appendTo head, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag

Comment: I've tried, but it somehow makes the card disappear.

Comment: would you able to create https://jsfiddle.net/ for to duplicate?

Comment: This is what I made (my first language is Korean, just for your information): https://jsfiddle.net/tomanota/jxr2oygc/

Comment: If you press the plus button and fill out the form, it will communicate the form data to the server and then save it. The browser then gets the menus from the database and creates cards out of them. Now it's disconnected from the server and the categories are empty, so maybe you should create a dummy card to see how the CSS functions

Comment: once add objectid manually with + it seems working ok `.append(`<style type="text/css">#` + objectId + `>`

Comment: Still no difference unfortunately. I also tried replacing the backticks with double-quotation. My code now looks like this: $(`#${objectId}`).append("<style type='text/css'>div#" + objectId + ":after {display: block; position:fixed; height: 1rem; width: 35px; padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; margin: 10px 0 0 40px; background-color: #f07303; color: #ffffff; font-size: 0.8rem; content: 'SALE'}</style>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by toggling classes. Much cleaner this way. Once the number of my cards reaches a significant amount, the browser seems to ignore or object to applying any more jQuery-controlled CSS snippets associated with each ObjectId (perhaps to minimize overhead, in my conjecture).

CSS:

```
div.sale-sign:after {
  display: block;
  position:fixed;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
  background-color: #f07303;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  content: "SALE"
}

a.grayscale {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
}
        
div.sold-sign:after {
  display: block;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
  background-color: #818181;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  content: "SOLD";
}
```

jQuery:

```
if (isDiscounted > 0) {
  $(`#${objectId}> div > div.price`).html(`<del>￦ ${numberWithCommas(price)}</del><br> → ￦ ${numberWithCommas(price - isDiscounted)}`);
  $(`#${objectId}`).toggleClass("sale-sign");
}

if (isSoldOut === true) {
  $(`#${objectId} > div > div`).toggleClass("sold-sign");
  $(`#${objectId} > div > a`).toggleClass("grayscale");
}
```